# Прозрачный фон текстуры отрисовывается черным на устройстве и нормально в редакторе Unity

Tags: unity3d

У меня есть элементы UI RawImage, в которых стоят текстуры, полученные как RenderTexture, в моём самодельном RenderPass'е. Мой RenderPass вызывается после обработки постпроцессинга и рендерит то, что видит камера, в текстуру. Потом эти текстуры уже используются на RawImage объектах. Текстуры получаются с отрендеренным, нужным мне, объектом, после пост процессинга. Фон получается полностью прозрачным.
В редакторе всё работает гладко. RawImage отображает только видимые области текстуры, но когда я запускаю это на Android (iOS пока не пробовал), то всё что прозрачное, становится просто сплошным черным цветом.

У меня нет возможности настраивать Clear у камеры, потому что используется Universal Render Pipeline.
Параметр Filtering в Renderer'е, который использует камера, пишущая в текстуру, настроен так, что видит только нужный мне объект, у которого выбран соответствующий слой. Читал на Unity форуме, кто-то рекомендовал отключить MSAA.. Отключил, не помогло. URP обновил до последней, тоже не помогло.

Вот вопрос, в чем может быть здесь отличие того, что происходит в редакторе и на устройстве и как это исправить?

Вот пара примеров того, что в редакторе и того же самого на устройстве. Здесь у RawImage этой картошки должен быть прозрачный фон. Это снимается в текстуру, когда ни дерево сзади, ни что иное не видно:

[image: в редакторе]
[image: на устройстве]

upd:
наткнулся только что на [этот пост](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/urp-backgrounds-transparency-is-lost-on-render-texture-when-post-processing-is-enabled-on-the-camera). Похоже, что это намеренно сделано.. Можно ли это как-то побороть?